# ASP.Net Core Angular2 template plus Auth0 not working

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, auth0

I am trying to build an Angular2 webfrontend with Auth0 support in VS2015. I used the template mentioned in this article http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2016/10/04/angular2-template-for-visual-studio/ and tried to follow the Auth0 guide for Angular2 at https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/spa/angular2 but i ended up with something that wont start. It worked before i added Auth0 and i think it has to do with how i added Auth0 but i can't work it out. I will paste my current error message below but really trying to find the steps needed to add Auth0 to this common dotnet VS2015 template. I am using this particular template as it is the main one that seems to get all the main features like hot code changes working in visual studio.

```
Exception: Call to Node module failed with error: ReferenceError: Auth0Lock is not defined
at new Auth (C:\Code\videofilenameinfo\VideoFileInfo\NameParserWebsite\ClientApp\dist\main-server.js:230:26)
at AppView._View_AppComponent_Host0.createInternal (AppComponent_Host.ngfactory.js:15:20)
at AppView.create (C:\Code\videofilenameinfo\VideoFileInfo\NameParserWebsite\node_modules\@angular\core\bundles\core.umd.js:9419:25)
at ComponentFactory.create (C:\Code\videofilenameinfo\VideoFileInfo\NameParserWebsite\node_modules\@angular\core\bundles\core.umd.js:6029:40)
at ApplicationRef_.bootstrap (C:\Code\videofilenameinfo\VideoFileInfo\NameParserWebsite\node_modules\@angular\core\bundles\core.umd.js:7051:44)
at C:\Code\videofilenameinfo\VideoFileInfo\NameParserWebsite\node_modules\@angular\core\bundles\core.umd.js:6960:93
at Array.forEach (native)
at PlatformRef_._moduleDoBootstrap (C:\Code\videofilenameinfo\VideoFileInfo\NameParserWebsite\node_modules\@angular\core\bundles\core.umd.js:6960:46)
at C:\Code\videofilenameinfo\VideoFileInfo\NameParserWebsite\node_modules\@angular\core\bundles\core.umd.js:6928:31
at ZoneDelegate.invoke (C:\Code\videofilenameinfo\VideoFileInfo\NameParserWebsite\node_modules\zone.js\dist\zone-node.js:232:26)
```

Comment: Found a suggestion to change "declare var Auth0Lock: any;" to "let Auth0Lock: any = require('auth0-lock').default;" that resulted in the error changing to Exception: Call to Node module failed with error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'createElement' of undefined
at C:\Code\videofilenameinfo\VideoFileInfo\NameParserWebsite\node_modules\auth0-lock\lib\ui\box\header.js:138:27
at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Code\videofilenameinfo\VideoFileInfo\NameParserWebsite\node_modules\auth0-lock\lib\ui\box\header.js:141:2)
at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out the problem was prerender-module. Auth0 does not support prerender. Auth0 staff pointed it out to me.(https://auth0.com/forum/t/asp-net-core-angular2-and-auth0-not-working/4170)

The key part is disabling the server-side prerendering by removing the asp-prerender-module attribute from the `<app>` element in Views/Home/Index.cshtml.

Comment: I had the same issue.  How did you get it to work?  Did you have to put the CDN url in the head?

Comment: @minerva yes put that in your _layout.cshtml page inside the head tag.

Comment: I placed the cdn url in the head tag, however, I'm still getting the same error ' Auth0Lock is not defined'.  Could you post your sample project with Auth0 lock integrated?

Comment: @minerva sorry missed the comment. look at https://auth0.com/forum/t/asp-net-core-angular2-and-auth0-not-working/4170 basically i think you still have not removed the asp-prerender-module attribute from the <app> element in Views/Home/Index.cshtml"